# How to programmatically raise a Qt Window/Widget when not the active application (windows)?

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, qwidget

I have an application which has multiple processes with GUI components which need to be coordinated as if they were one process (Lets call it a GUI system and say it uses TCP sockets to coordinate the components).

To that end, if one window in the system is activated, a message will be sent to all other windows in the system to make sure they are raised above any window not belonging to our GUI system.

It seems that the closest I can do in purely native Qt is to call QWidget.activateWindow().
Various other commands eg, show, raise do not appear to work if the process is not the active Windows process.

The problem with having all other windows call activate window is that it steels the focus away from the window which I just clicked on, making that window unusable (unless I somehow call activate on it when all the other processes have completed their activate command - but that introduces a lot of complexity and fragility).

Answer (score 1):

While trying to solve my problem,  I found many people out there with similar problems.

It would appear there is no Qt Native way to bring up a window when not the active process.

Many point to using the win32 API but it was hard to find all the parts of how to mix PyQt and win32 API to just bring a window to the front when not the active application so here's my best attempt:

```
import win32gui
import win32con

hwnd = self.widget.winId()
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE)
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE)
```

I hate that it takes two calls but it seems to work.

Comment: I think its intended by Windows that this doesn’t work unless the currently active application explicitly allows the window to come to the foreground, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld This is certainly close related to my issue. But I am not actually looking to make the slave windows "foreground".   --Keyboard input is directed to the window, and various visual cues are changed for the user. -- I want to avoid the change in focus, and just change the Z-order of the windows.